# Security considerations when creating an email form on the web

Tags: php, forms, security, email

I know I have to consider about
**mail header injection**,

and are there more thing that
I need to know before I make form mail thing?

I want mail, and I feel that
I have to set up form mail thing
in my page, but I heard that
mail thing is dangerous if I 
do not consider all security things.

Comment: If it's only meant for sending mail to you, hard-code the recipient address. If it's meant for sending anyhwere, don't rely solely on a single security mechanism. If all you have is a CAPTCHA and a spammer figures out how to break or subvert it, you're toast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-  avoid spam,
use captcha or other thing to prevent spam.

the link talk about it :
[Are you human? (or How to prevent spam)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076/are-you-human-or-how-to-prevent-spam)

2 -  Prevent Duplicate Submissions