# get the alphabets from the image using java..!

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I am looking for some code which can get me the alphabets present in the image. As per my understanding OCR works fine with the plain white background. I am looking for something which gives me the characters or alphabets in some random image background except the alphabets. Can anyone help me out in this regard..?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks as is you were trying to break some CAPTCHA, are you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448963/has-recaptcha-been-cracked-hacked-ocrd-defeated-broken

Comment: not exactly CAPTCHA. I am just trying wih some application which can separate alphabets from images when the background is not the plain white.

Answer (score 0):

Some image preprocessing is necessary to remove the background noise before feeding it to the OCR engine. For OCR, I use Tesseract. Here are some Java frontend or library that use it:

[VietOCR](http://vietocr.sf.net)
[Tess4J](http://tess4j.sf.net)