# Is ReCaptcha too weak?

Tags: security, validation, playframework, captcha, recaptcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has reCaptcha been cracked / hacked / OCR'd / defeated / broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448963/has-recaptcha-been-cracked-hacked-ocrd-defeated-broken)

I recognized that during some time reCaptcha is used without the horizontal line. I do not like the changes. Referring to some articles, google's captcha service is getting weaker and weaker. Do you guys think reCaptcha is still the best captcha there is, or should i think about using another implementation?

(I'm using play in my current project, and I'm also not very happy with the implementation play supplies.)

Comment: The only way to tell if the CAPTCHA is weak is to see how often it has been broken.

Comment: You should also check out the information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448963/has-recaptcha-been-cracked-hacked-ocrd-defeated-broken/549859#549859. ReCAPTCHA has always been broken, but then again *all* CAPTCHAs are broken even before implementation.

Comment: As @AviD says - I think this is a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a read of [this article at allspammedup from January 2011 which gives statistics on a crack rate of 17.5% on google reCAPTCHA](http://www.allspammedup.com/2011/01/google-recaptcha-cracked/)

Two definites - people are getting better at programming algorithms to get around CAPTCHAs, and CAPTCHAs themselves are getting to the limit of being understood by peoples, so yeas - the effective strength of CAPTCHAs is decreasing, at at some point another solution will have to be used.

Comment: I already read that link, but thank you. Those articles lead me to my question. I have doubts with the implementation, but I don't see any alternative systems that can be used instead of reCaptcha..