# Prevent spam bots from hitting Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku

I have a Rails 5 app in production hosted on Heroku. I recently noticed a particularly high load on the servers and on further investigation it looks as though it's all from a group of spam bots.

These bots were hitting an 'email to friend' form that I had on the show page and available to logged-out users. I've since made the form available only to logged-in and authenticated users. I also deleted the specific record that the bots were targeting in the db, yet this hasn't done anything to stop the bots from hitting the route. (They only seem to be targeting a specific record...)

I then installed the [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) gem to try and throttle requests to this specific route (as well as the `sign_up` path), but the problem I have is that these spam requests originate from a different ip address *every single time* and the rack-attack gem only throttles requests from a single ip.

Can anyone provide any assistance on how to prevent these bots from hitting my site?

Here is the print out from the Heroku logs:

```
2016-11-26T08:01:22.784341+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/jobs/389-commercial-vehicle-technician-northside-truck-van-york-mercedes-benz-uk-ltd/email_to_friend" host=www.example.com request_id=02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836 fwd="203.160.52.159" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=1812
2016-11-26T08:01:22.757585+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] Started POST "/jobs/389-commercial-vehicle-technician-northside-truck-van-york-mercedes-benz-uk-ltd/email_to_friend" for 203.160.52.159 at 2016-11-26 08:01:22 +0000
2016-11-26T08:01:22.759320+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836]   
2016-11-26T08:01:22.759371+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/jobs/389-commercial-vehicle-technician-northside-truck-van-york-mercedes-benz-uk-ltd/email_to_friend"):
2016-11-26T08:01:22.759421+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836]   
2016-11-26T08:01:22.759493+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.759535+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.759575+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.759639+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.759726+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.759685+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.759766+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.759905+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.759944+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760009+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760265+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760333+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760365+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760394+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760422+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/heroku-deflater-60d92ba0f8ae/lib/heroku-deflater/skip_binary.rb:19:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760478+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/deflater.rb:35:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760522+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/heroku-deflater-60d92ba0f8ae/lib/heroku-deflater/serve_zipped_assets.rb:50:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760552+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760581+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:83:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760610+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760650+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760699+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760741+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760782+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
2016-11-26T08:01:22.760849+00:00 app[web.1]: [02689424-de9c-4a25-96c8-8f510a587836] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add ReCAPTCHA to your forms. This could filter out most of bots.

[This is one of ruby gems to add reCaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha)

However, there are some drawbacks according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319942/preventing-bot-form-submission). Accepted answer has very good description for you what to do.