# How to ignore HTML element from tabindex?

Tags: html, tabindex

Is there any way in HTML to tell the browser not to allow tab indexing on particular elements?

On my page though there is a sideshow which is rendered with jQuery, when you tab through that, you get a lot of tab presses before the tab control moves to the next visible link on the page as all the things being tabbed through are hidden to the user visually.

Answer (score 716, accepted):

You can use [`tabindex="-1"`](http://jehiah.cz/a/tabindex).

Only do this if you are certain it does not remove functionality for keyboard users.

The [W3C HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute) supports negative `tabindex` values:

> **If the value is a negative integer**
> The user agent must set the element's tabindex focus flag, but should not allow the element to be reached using sequential focus navigation.

---

Watch out though that this is a HTML5 feature and might not work with old browsers.
To be [W3C HTML 4.01 standard (from 1999)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) compliant, `tabindex` would need to be positive.

---

Sample usage below in pure HTML.

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return false">Focusable</a>
<a tabindex="-1" href="#" onclick="return false">Not focusable</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return false">Focusable</a>
```

Comment: It appears Google Chrome does not support the -1, which makes sense since technically tabIndex only supports 0 -32767 according to [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1)`W3`.  So when I did this; I used 500. Hackish; but worked.

Comment: @Flea As of version 23, Google Chrome supports -1 on tabindex. Not sure how long ago that happened, perhaps prior to 23.

I tested "-1" in Chrome 23, Firefox 18, IE8, IE9, and Opera 12.11 and it worked across the board.

Comment: I've edited the answer to link to the updated HTML5 specification. `tabindex` now allows to have negative values.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Thank you for your edit. I re-added the reference to the W3C HTML4 spec for browser compability.

Comment: Supported since IE 5.01 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534654(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @jimmykup Chrome 38, tabindex=-1 participates in tab stop round robin.

Comment: Also start off your tab index with 1, not 0 like some references say is OK. It's not.

Comment: @MikeBethany Interesting - do you have a source?

Comment: @Martin Yes, here are examples. Tabindex 0: https://gist.github.com/mikbe/e4b68c89f678556afd8e -- Tabindex 1: https://gist.github.com/mikbe/6cb1254a3cca53a2b8d2 -- Notice the tabindex 0 version jumps from the tabindex 0 to the address bar while tabindex 1 version properly goes from 1 to 2.

Comment: @MikeBethany I meant a source, a reference, an official statement, a w3 link or similar, but your claim is empirical and maybe not applicable for all browsers.

Comment: @Martin "...and maybe not applicable for all browsers." And that's my point. Your tabindex should work with all browsers so if one of the major browsers has an issue you have to code for that. I also only care about empirical facts, I don't care about hypotheticals.

Comment: See my answer which works for almost all modern chrome, and for most browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38005077/681830

Comment: Note for GWT developers. Since GWT has special handling for -1 value, set any offer negative value (e.g. `tabIndex="-2"`)

Comment: Ok, and what is GWT ?

Answer (score 160):

Don't forget that, even though `tabindex` is all lowercase in the specs and in the HTML, in *Javascript*/the DOM that property is called `tabIndex`.

Don't lose your mind trying to figure out why your programmatically altered tab indices calling `element.tabindex = -1` isn't working. Use `element.tabIndex = -1`.

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Eh, I was glad to read it, and I probably would have missed it if it were buried as a comment.

Answer (score 15):

If these are elements naturally in the tab order like buttons and anchors, removing them from the tab order with `tabindex="-1"` is kind of an accessibility smell. If they're providing duplicate functionality removing them from the tab order is ok, and consider adding `aria-hidden="true"` to these elements so assistive technologies will ignore them.

Answer (score 10):

If you are working in a browser that doesn't support  `tabindex="-1"`, you may be able to get away with just giving the things that need to be skipped **a really high tab index**. For example `tabindex="500"` basically moves the object's tab order to the end of the page.

I did this for a long data entry form with a button thrown in the middle of it. It's not a button people click very often so I didn't want them to accidentally tab to it and press enter. `disabled` wouldn't work because it's a button.

Answer (score 5):

Just add the attribute `disabled` to the element (or use jQuery to do it for you). Disabled prevents the input from being focused or selected at all.

Comment: Which version of Chrome?

Comment: Chrome 49.0.2623.75 (64 bit).

Comment: My version is 51.0.2704.103. Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z766dvuu/). You might have the wrong code, you never know.

Comment: @AtulChaudhary, how doesn't it work? You can still focus it?

Comment: once the fields are disabled they remain disabled and it is an issue in IOS9 but seems to be working in IOS10

Comment: For reference, `disabled` also disables clicking of the element, seemingly.

Answer (score 5):

The way to do this is by adding `tabindex="-1"`. By adding this to a specific element, it becomes **unreachable** by the keyboard navigation. There is a great article [here](https://kolosek.com/tabindex/) that will help you further understand **tabindex**.