# Event triggered when using tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I wanted to know which event is triggered when I go on a page and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> which results in going through the links.

I want to whenever someone uses the tab to go through the page `<a>` tags it will force the hover event on the link, or will do any other code for instance, the element is `visibility:hidden` but when the user is using the tab, the browser is actually going through the hidden `<a>` tag and therefore cause it to be `visibility:visible`.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the browser from "tabbing" to your hidden links, you can try setting a negative tab index on the links: [How to ignore HTML element from tabindex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192859/html-remove-element-from-tab-index)

The "event" that occurs when a link is tabbed over is the "focus" event, styled via the pseudo-class :focus.