# Why would an `a` tag need `tabindex=0`?

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm working on a web app, and one of the repeated `a` (anchor) elements does not get keyboard focus as I tab through the page. Only if I add `tabindex=0` can I tab to it.

(Although my goal is to make the focus visible, I'm determining whether an element gets focus by using a snippet of jQuery:

```
// Whenever I hit tab, show me which element has focus
$('main').on('keydown',function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

  if (keyCode == 9) { 
    console.log("focus is now on ", $(':focus'));
  } 
});
```

)

This confuses me. According to [the specs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#interactive-content), "The tabindex attribute can also make any element into interactive content" - but `a` is one of the ones they list as interactive by default.

And again, from an accessibility article:

> A [tabindex] value of 0 indicates that the element should be placed in the
>   default navigation order. This allows elements that are **not natively
>   focusable** (such as <div>, <span>, and <p>) to receive keyboard focus.
>   Of course one should generally use links and form controls for all
>   interactive elements...
>   (http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex)

What would cause an anchor element to be skipped as I tab through the interactive elements of a page?

Comment: Does the a tag have an href? If its interactivity comes solely from javascript, that could explain it.

Comment: Related: [Remove element from tab index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192859/html-remove-element-from-tab-index)

Comment: There can be a variety of reasons. Please show us what properties the `<a>` tags have that are not tabbing.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As per your question:

> What would cause an anchor element to be skipped as I tab through the
>   interactive elements of a page?

If you add `tabindex="-1"` the element will be skipped.
And if your `<a>` tag has no `href`, it will be skipped as well.

Comment: No `href` - that was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Then, how to focus If I have an anchor `tag` without attribute `href`?

Comment: @Rashid it means that anchor tag was most probably misused and you should replace it with another HTML element, for example, button.

Answer (score 0):

If a tabindex of “-1″ is used, the element it’s applied to will no longer be keyboard focusable.

You can check the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute) for it.