# tabindex="-1" being ignored in Safari (textarea fields)

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have some textareas that I don't want to be tabbable, and set the tabindex attribute to be -1.

Chrome/Firefox are working as expected, but Safari allows tabbing between textareas still. Any idea how to disallow this?

Example:

```html
<textarea class="tip-question-response" rows="10" value='' maxlength="400" tabindex=-1></textarea>
<textarea class="tip-question-response" rows="10" value='' maxlength="400" tabindex=-1></textarea>
<textarea class="tip-question-response" rows="10" value='' maxlength="400" tabindex=-1></textarea>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qe3rvamz/

Comment: Maybe but the `-1` in parentheses? Like `"-1"`. Also looking at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192859/html-remove-element-from-tab-index and a user said he set it too 500 and it worked.

Comment: Tried parentheses as well... it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Hmm, that is very odd!

Comment: I found this, and maybe it is a setting on Safari, the link is: http://www.lost-in-code.com/tag/safari-tabindex-not-working/. Maybe try going to `Preferences > Advanced > Press Tab…` In Safari?

Comment: Michael-- the main issue is actually that I don't want other people to click the tab arrows on mobile safari in iOS for something specific. Regular safari behaves the same way so it seems to be something safari related in general.