# How to control what elements are targeted by the key TAB using pure CSS?

Tags: html

Considering the following code:

```css
button{background:yellow;}
button:focus{outline:red 5px solid;}

button:nth-of-type(1){color:green;}
button:nth-of-type(2){color:orange;}
button:nth-of-type(3){color:blue;}
button:nth-of-type(4){color:grey;}
button:nth-of-type(5){color:purple;}
```

```html
<section>
  <button type="button">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button">Button 3</button>
  <button type="button">Button 4</button>
  <button type="button">Button 5</button>
</section>
```

Note that when clicking on the key tab on your keyboard it make the focus jump from the first button to the next and so on all the way to the last before it moves to the browser elements.

My question is if is there a way to skip "Button 3" when focus is on "Bottom 2" and I press the key tab? I would be happy to know that there is a CSS property to control this but if not javascript solutions are also welcome.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML remove element from tab index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192859/html-remove-element-from-tab-index)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve ("why is there a 3rd button between 2nd and 4th buttons and focusable if it shouldn't be focused in-between these 2nd and 4th buttons?") but messing with what is perceivable not being focusable causes accessibility problems (and ergonomics ones I guess). [W3C/WAI Creating Logical Tab Order with the Tabindex Attribute](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Creating_Logical_Tab_Order_with_the_Tabindex_Attribute) has a description of the problems and interesting resources about it. You can hide the 3rd button or disable it if it makes sense in your real project.

Comment: I just used buttons to illustrate the problem. I mostly need a way to make a certain element that would normally be focused when pressing TAB as inputs, buttons and tables to be skipped when pressing TAB. Tabindex does it but it goes on the markup. I was hopping to find a way to do it with pure css but as per conversation with @Derek朕會功夫 , ```nav-index``` never became a thing. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would be surprised, but this time it's actually not CSS or JS, but HTML doing the work.

```css
button{background:yellow;}
button:focus{outline:red 5px solid;}

button:nth-of-type(1){color:green;}
button:nth-of-type(2){color:orange;}
button:nth-of-type(3){color:blue;}
button:nth-of-type(4){color:grey;}
button:nth-of-type(5){color:purple;}
```

```html
<section>
  <button type="button">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" tabindex="-1">Button 3</button>
  <button type="button">Button 4</button>
  <button type="button">Button 5</button>
</section>
```

---

Or with JS,

```
[].map.call(document.getElementsByClassName("no-tab"), function(e){ e.tabIndex = -1; });
```

Comment: Oh wow!! This is very awesome. Thanks for the link too. Do you know if is there anyway to control it with CSS?

Comment: @ViniciusSantana `nav-index` was suggested and [included in CSS3 draft, but was later removed.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#changes-since-2012) So basically you are sticked with HTML to control your tab sequences.

Comment: I meant something like button:nth-of-type(3){ tabindex:-1; } instead of <button tabindex="-1">.

Comment: @ViniciusSantana Read my comment, it answered your question.

Comment: Yeah. We replied at the same time. You are right. No browser support at all for it http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_nav-index.asp . :(

Comment: @ViniciusSantana I guess you are trying to remove a lot of elements from the tab sequence. In that case, just set them with JS `[].map.call(document.getElementsByClassName("no-tab"), function(e){ e.tabIndex = -1; })`

Comment: That's an alternative but still would require me to edit the markup adding and removing classes. I would like to be able to control that property with the styles only without the use of classes.

Comment: @ViniciusSantana Well you can always pass in whatever CSS selector you are using to `.querySelectorAll` like this `document.querySelectorAll("button:nth-of-type(4)")`