# How can I remove an svg element from the taborder?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

In the following [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/26ga4wn8KJlQnYrZb3Id?p=preview)

I have 3 divs listed in order from top to bottom.

**Problem**

In Firefox: when I tab to each div, it does so after each keypress. This is the expected behavior I want to see: 
*

1. hit tab: dotted line is around div1
2. hit tab: dotted line is around div2
3. hit tab: dotted line is around div3

HOWEVER,

In **Internet Explorer**, it takes 2 keypresses of the tab key to move to the next div. It appears as if the browser wants to stop at the 'svg' element:

1. hit tab: dotted line is around div1
2. hit tab: NO dotted line but active element is now on the svg element
3. hit tab: dotted line is around div2*

My question is how can I  bypass the IE browser from stopping on the 'svg' element in the tab order so it behaves the way I had reported in Firefox?

You can monitor the behavior with the following console log:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode === 9) {
      console.log(document.activeElement);
    }
  })
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5192859/104380