# Tabkey navigation HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So i have 3 buttons: "Cancel", "Prev." and "Next", is there a way to limit tab navigation only to these 3 buttons. Desired tab key cycle: `Next->Prev->Cancel->Next->...`
Any ideas how to achieve this?

Edit:
I must decorate every element that i don't want to be accessible via tab sequential navigation with `tabindex="-1"`? what if i have a lot of elements that i don't want to be accessible this way?

Edit 2: The answers described bellow make the tab key jump through address bar of the browser, so it is not a good solution for me.

Comment: What else do you have?

Comment: @G.Stoynev nothing, basicaly only markup for this buttons and tabindex on them to set the order

Comment: Similar to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192859/html-remove-element-from-tab-index

Comment: Has this question been answered?

Comment: @ksav no. i found a solution. tabintex doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

A negative `tabindex` value means that the element should be focusable, but should not be reachable via sequential keyboard navigation;

```html
<button tabindex="1">Next</button>
<button tabindex="3">Prev</button>
<button tabindex="2">Cancel</button>

<button tabindex="-1">Other</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using tabindex with a negative value should do the trick, I think.
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute

Edit:
Yep, it does: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgmxmsfm/
At least on my Chrome.

```
<a tabindex="1" href="#">first</a><br/>
<a tabindex="3" href="#">third</a><br/>
<a tabindex="-3" href="#">nope</a><br/>
<a tabindex="2" href="#">second</a>
```