# tabindex -1 not working for child elements

Tags: html, accessibility, tabindex

I have a div tag with some content getting loaded inside it. The content inside can have buttons, anchor elements, etc. which are focusable. I do not have control over the content but I can modify the 'div' tag attributes.

My problem is the focus still goes to the content (anchor, buttons, etc.) even if I specify the tabIndex -1 to the div tag.

```html
<!-- HTML content here -->
<div tabindex="-1" id="externalContent">
  <div>
    ...
    <button>click me</button> <!-- Focus shouldn't come here -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- HTML content here -->
```

Is there a way to skip the entire content while tabbing ? It's certainly not working with the above code.

Comment: You can use tabindex="-1"....  Watch out though that this is a HTML5 feature and might not work with old browsers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192859/how-to-ignore-html-element-from-tabindex

Comment: maybe you can use jquery to get tabindex="-1" to all possible elements inside the div...

Comment: Why do you want to prevent focus going to the content? If the content is actually interactive - ie if you can click the buttons/links with the mouse - you should generally let them take keyboard focus too.

Comment: The content inside the 'externalContent' here is partially visible on page load and hence for a11y, I need to skip it from the tab order. I do not want to append tabindex=-1 for every child since I need to reverse it once the content is fully visible.

Comment: A common usecase: show a dialog on webpage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Setting `tabindex="-1"` allows you to set an element’s focus with script, but does *not* put it in the tab order of the page. It also does not pull the children of something *out* of keyboard tab order.

`tabindex="-1"` is handy when you need to move focus to something you have updated via script or outside of user action.

If you are trying to remove an element from tabindex altogether, whether for screen readers or keyboard users, you will likely have to choose between one of these:

1. Hide it altogether (via `display: none`),
2. Use script on the element so that when it receives focus, the script shifts the focus somewhere else.

Without context (a working URL, a reason that you want to do this), this sounds very much like the *opposite* of accessibility. I encourage you not to mess with focus unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: "Setting tabindex="-1"...does not pull something out of keyboard tab order."  On what browser?  Setting tabindex to -1 has always worked for me to skip over an object in the tab order.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say that it does not pull an item's *children* out of tab order. Edited the answer accordingly. In the OP's question, it will not pull the nested `<button>` out of tab order, just the container (which does not natively get focus anyway since it is is a `<div>`).

Comment: Yeah using 'script' is the only option I could find too. Can't display none since the content inside my 'externalContent' div is partially visible on page load.

Comment: Was hoping to get a way to do this without an external event listener though!

Comment: it does pull the children of an svg in <object> out of the order.

Answer (score 41):

Not sure why nobody has mentioned `visibility: hidden` yet. Setting `display: none` can in some cases mess up logic when dealing with dimensions of non-visual elements. `visibility` will persist the dimensions just like `opacity: 0` would do, but also disable any tabbable children.

Example:

```
<div style="visibility: hidden;">
    <a href="#">I'm only tabbable if my parent is visible!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Setting tabindex="-1" on the parent will not remove tabindex from the children but visibility: hidden on the parent will remove tabindex from the children.

Comment: Thanks! This great solution saved me a lot of work. This should be the accepted answer, in my opinion.

Comment: One gotcha -- with visibility, a child can set `visibility:visible` on itself, which would allow it to receive keyboard focus even within a `visibility: hidden` ancestor: https://jakearchibald.com/2014/visible-undoes-hidden/

Answer (score 25):

It is possible leave an element **BOTH** **visible** and **unfocusable**, together with its children.

It's done via the HTML property `inert`: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#inert.

It's not widely supported yet, but there is a polyfill: https://github.com/WICG/inert.

`npm install --save wicg-inert`

```
require('wicg-inert')

<section inert>
  I am visible, but not focusable! 
</section>
```

Comment: fwiw i think you do a:
`<section inert />`

Comment: @TheDembinski, uh likely, I used the react syntax throughout.

Comment: `<section inert={true}>` -> `<section inert>`

Comment: Dissapointingly support is still limited all browsers requires enabling with a flag [Can I Use HTMLELement API: inert](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlelement_inert)

Answer (score 0):

The nearest you can go is using an `iframe` element, injecting your HTML inside using javascript.

```
<a href="somewhere.html">first link</a>
<iframe id="iframeid" tabindex="-1"></iframe>
<a href="somewhere_else.html">second link</a>

<script>
    document.getElementById('iframeid').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML="<button>click me</button>";
</script>
```

But, this will lead to accessibility problems, like announcing links or buttons which can't be accessed by your keyboard.

Comment: This isn't viable for me because of accessibility concerns.

Comment: @AdarshKonchady There's no answer to your question then. You can't be accessible if you specifically ask something which will lead to accessibility concerns.

Comment: @AdarshKonchady You should also read Aardrian warning with caution: "this sounds very much like the opposite of accessibility."

Answer (score 0):

```
[tab-index="-1"] > * {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This hides any interactive children from tab navigation or mouse clicks, but leaves the parent in the shadow DOM and leaves all sizes of parent and children.

Comment: There's no shadow DOM involved. Visibility hidden wasn't an option here since the content still needed to be visible partially.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, it should be `[tabindex="-1"]`

Answer (score -2):

For making tabindex -1 for child elements, lets say you have a wrapper div, 
// answer with respect to react, when we don't want grid filter to be accessible if its collapsed
//this answer is for a special case - where we dont have refs and tabIndex Props does matter for big nested elements
// Render method

// if Input and Button are from some kind(eg material UI) of Libraries which dont get tabIndex as a prop and doesnt give refs.

```
   render() {
    return (
    <div id="wrapper" tabIndex={isCollapsed ? -1 : 0 } >
      <div>
        <Input />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.changeTabIndex()
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
  if(prevState.isCollapsed !== this.state.isCollapsed) {
     this.changeTabIndex();
  }
}

changeTabIndex() {
   const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
     const buttons = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("button");
     const inputs = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("input");
     const arr = Array.from(buttons).concat(Array.from(inputs));
     arr.foreach((elem) => { elem.setAttribute("tabIndex", this.state.isCollapsed ? -1 : 0 )});
}
```