# How to remove tabindex on whole div?

Tags: jquery

I have this :

```
<div class="glass">
<input />
<input />
<select>
<option>aaaa</option>
</select>
</div>
<input />
```

What i want is to remove div with glass class from tabing that is cloned, so when i do tab it skip that div. Any suggestion ?

Im doing clone element :

```
 this.background = jQuery(this.content.nativeElement).clone()
        .addClass('glass').removeAttr('tabindex');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore HTML element from tabindex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192859/how-to-ignore-html-element-from-tabindex)

Comment: im using clone...how is that same?

Comment: can you provide a working example with https://jsfiddle.net/ or the internal code editor ? in general a div is not focused on tab. if you want the inputs to be ignored you should add `.find(':input')` before setting the tabindex to negative

Answer (score 1):

based on the [w3c specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute), the tabindex should be set to a negative value. Your code should look like this:

```
 this.background = jQuery(this.content.nativeElement).clone()
    .addClass('glass').prop('tabindex', -1);
```

Comment: its not working...it still goes in cloned element with tab