# How to prevent links from being tab stops when they're not hidden with display block?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement a simple dropdown with a slideDown effect. To build this effect I used a CSS `transition` applied to the `height` property.

Problem is that if I press the `Tab ↹` key, any targetable element (tab stops) inside the dropdown will be targeted, even when it is hidden as I am not using `display: none`.

Here's the code:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

dropdown.style.setProperty('height', 'auto', 'important');
dropdown.style.setProperty('height', dropdown.clientHeight + 'px');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
#dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 330ms linear;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 200px;
}

#dropdown:not(.active) {
  height: 0 !important;
}

#dropdown.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me!</button>

<div id="dropdown">
  <a href="#">I should not be accessible with tab when dropdown is hidden</a>
</div>

<div id="info">This link will be focused after three tabs, instead of two: <a href="#">Tab me!</a></div>
```

I have tried to modify the code a little bit using the `transitionend` event to add and remove `display: none` when the transition ends thus making any targetable elements inside the dropdown untargetable, but this messes up with the starting animation of the transition.

See:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

dropdown.style.setProperty('height', 'auto', 'important');
dropdown.style.setProperty('height', dropdown.clientHeight + 'px');
dropdown.classList.add('hidden');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('active'))
    dropdown.classList.remove('hidden');


  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
});

dropdown.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
  dropdown.classList.add('hidden');
});
```

```css
#dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 330ms linear;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 200px;
}

#dropdown:not(.active) {
  height: 0 !important;
}

#dropdown.active {
  visibility: visible;
}

a {
  display: block; /* so it doesn't move when dropdown is hidden */
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me!</button>

<div id="dropdown">
  <a href="#">I should not be accessible with tab when dropdown is hidden</a>
</div>

<div id="info">This link will now be focused after <strong>two</strong> tabs, as expected: <a href="#">Tab me!</a></div>
```

Comment: so, you need the tab key to not do its natural function?

Comment: @assembler I need the tab key to do its natural function, but as I'm not actually hidding the dropdown with display: none, the tab key will stop at the link inside the dropdown, which is not what the user expects.

Comment: so, if `display: none;` the tab should jump to the next component... right?

Comment: @assembler Exactly. If the `display` property in `#dropdown` is set to `none`, the link inside it won't be targetable by the tab key.

Comment: set the component `tabindex` to a negative value according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/tabIndex

Comment: @assembler I am not able to know the content of the dropdown, so the only way would be to get all child elements of it and add this attribute, which I don't think is an efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting attribute "tabindex" to -1, this should prevent link from selecting with tab. You can also simply remove this attribute with JS when dropdown is active

Comment: `tabindex` can only be applied to the element that can't be selected with tab, not the parent. If I want to do this with JS I would have to get all content from a dropdown and add this attribute (and remove it when is visible). Is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the element’s tabIndex (-1 to make it untargetable, very high number to make it targeted last). [How to ignore HTML element from tabindex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5192859/6119323)