# CSS: checkbox not checked when spacebar is pressed

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have the simple form below (and here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxKrex).
The checkbox works when you click on it, but I would like that when you have the focus on it (after a "tab" from the textfield) and press spacebar, it would be marked as well. However, it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

**index.html**

```css
.labelCheckbox {
        display: contents;
    }
    
    .checkbox label {
        float: left;
        padding-left: 0px !important;
        font-size: initial;
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox] {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"]{
        display: none;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"] + label::before{
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid #135BCF;
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        height: 22px;
        width: 22px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 5px -2px 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        top: 3px;
        position: relative;
        float: initial;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before{
        content: '\2713';
    }
```

```html
<form action="/send.php" method="post" name="myForm">
      <label for="fname"></label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
        <label for="checkbox1" tabindex="0;"></label>
      <label class="labelCheckbox">&nbsp&nbspI agree</label>
      <button class="modalButton" type="submit" value="submit" id="submit2">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: http://wiki.accede-web.com/en/notices/interfaces-riches-javascript/checkbox-simulees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden;` on the `<input type="checkbox"/>` to check or uncheck with <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key. But you are using `opacity:0;` to hide the checkbox element, that's fine to hide the element:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity:0;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  outline:0;
  user-select:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #999;
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:22px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  top:7px;
  width:22px; 
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  content:'\2713';
}
input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
  border-color:#135BCF;
}
```

```html
<form action="/send.php" method="post" name="myForm">
  <label for="fname"></label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1" tabindex="-1"></label>
  <label class="labelCheckbox">I agree</label>
  <button class="modalButton" type="submit" value="submit" id="submit2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

To ignore the "real" checkbox on tabindex you need to set the [`tabindex` attribute to `-1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192919/3840840).

---

You can improve the custom checkbox element like the following:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity:0;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  margin-left:10px;
  outline:0;
  padding-left:5px;
  position:relative;
  user-select:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #999;
  content:'';
  height:22px;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  transform:translate(-100%,-50%);
  top:50%;
  width:22px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  content:'\2713';
}
input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
  border-color:#135BCF;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value=""/>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox1" tabindex="-1">I agree</label>
<button>OK</button>
```

With this checkbox element you can also click on the label text to check the checkbox. You can also focus the control with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> and check and uncheck the checkbox with <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

Comment: Please note that when you do that the focus is not visible in the checkbox and you need to do an extra tab to go to the button.

Comment: Looks good! It is not possible to have that "visible focus" on the checkbox anymore? The blue square when you have the focus on the checkbox?

Comment: what about with `ENTER` ?

Answer (score 2):

As you can't tick/untick the checkbox if it's not displayed,

I suggest you to use the `::after` pseudo-element to cover the regular checkbox.

See working snippet, with some comments:

```css
.labelCheckbox {
  display: contents;
}

.checkbox label {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  font-size: initial;
}

/* TAKIT: Added this */
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
}

/* TAKIT: Changed a little the style below */
input[type="checkbox"]::before {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: -0.33em;
  border: 1px solid #135BCF;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  content: '';
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before {
  content: '\2713';
}
```

```html
<form action="/send.php" method="post" name="myForm">
  <label for="fname"></label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1" tabindex="0;"></label>
  <label class="labelCheckbox">  I agree</label>
  <button class="modalButton" type="submit" value="submit" id="submit2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hope it helps.