# Make sure crawlers don't 'click' on button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my view:

```
= form_tag(new_demo_path, :method => "put", id: "demo-form") do
  = submit_tag "Try out demo", :name => nil
```

This will setup a demo environment which will be accessible for 7 days.  Of course I don't want search engines to click this.  Since it's a put request, will this be a problem?  Do I need to include something so they don't click this link?

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387496/how-to-prevent-robots-from-automatically-filling-up-a-form) may be helpful.

Comment: Captcha is a common tactic, to prevent bots from submitting forms

Comment: @GyaptiJain thanks, there seem to be lots of good tactics in there.  I don't want to use a captcha since I want to have as few steps necessary to convince potential users...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I found myself in a similar situation and I wrote a negative captcha plugin for Rails: https://github.com/markets/invisible_captcha. It's based on the honeypot strategy, the idea was to provide a better user experience.

More or less, you should add into your form:

```
<%= form_tag(new_demo_path, :method => "put", id: "demo-form") do %>
  <%= invisible_captcha %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
invisible_captcha only: [:new_demo] # assuming new_demo is the action that handles the form
```

Comment: That's indeed the strategy I just implemented (based on the link Gyapti gave).  This link describes it as well: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/11/honeypot-captcha.aspx/
Thanks!