# Alternatives to Email Verification to verify users signing up to React Native App

Tags: react-native, recaptcha, spam-prevention, email-verification

I want to implement some security measures to prevent spam bots from signing up to my app. Originally I was thinking of using email verification but I feel it's a but of an outdated method.

After looking online I found a few suggestions, such as captcha, recaptcha, honeypot etc.

I wanna know, what are RN developers out there using these days against spam bots (other than email verification)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

captcha or recaptcha should be enough, but you can combine it with other methods such as knowing the timestamp of the loaded app and the form submit and compare both (bots are very fast, but for signing in components humans take their time).
You could also add a phone verification SMS, or something similar, it all depends on how your app works.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387496/how-to-prevent-robots-from-automatically-filling-up-a-form) that is focused mainly in html forms but can also give you hints on using it in React Native.

I have used own captchas, [facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/login/), and SMS verification for different type of apps, depending on the complexity, privacy policy and data management, and use of phone numbers within the app (one app where the functionality depended entirely on your phone number, like whatsapp).

Comment: I am keen on using captcha and recaptcha butI tried to look for examples of RN apps using these methods online but can't find any ay... which led me to think whether do RN developers use something else

Comment: @Reuben it really depends on the app, for example you could only do SMS verification if your app allows it, but if it's an app where you don't want to do anything with the phone number then it's not worth the trouble for the user (always keep the user experience in mind). Captcha will be fine in this situacion. Other apps rely on 3rd party auth services like facebook's or google's, but again, it all depends on what you want to do with your app and your data privacy policies.