# detect *any* link in string with regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string, url, detect

This situation has no question yet.
I wan't to detect if a string contains any link, that is all combinations of http,ftp,https, and the www., etc

Basically I want to prevent a string to contain *any* link.

I currently use:

```
name.split(/\s+/).find_all { |u| u =~ /^https?:/ }).count
```

What would be the best way to prevent any links in strings?

Comment: Are you talking about HTML link (a tags) or just a URL string?

Comment: by splitting on whitespace, then searching, you're not utilizing the power of regexes. This is better: `fail if name =~ /\bhttps?:/`, although that won't catch all the link cases. Idk what your requirements are -- does "www.example.com" count? How about "example.com"? if so, it's hopeless because there's too many domains out there and maintenance would be a nightmare

Comment: you _can_ do this with regexen, but if your goal is to prevent users to display such links, they will _always_ find a way to circumvent that. Like : h t t p : // s t a c k o v e r f l o w . c o m

Comment: also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700163/detecting-a-naughty-or-nice-url-or-link-in-a-text-string?rq=1

Comment: @m_x yes my goal is to prevent any links in user submitted content. The best I can do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
errors.add(:name, "Your name cannot contain links") if name.match /\b(?:(?:mailto:\S+|(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/)?(?:\w+\.)+[a-z]{2,6})\b/
```

Which works quite good in almost all situations. 
Hacked together from several sources online