# Captcha alternatives to deter spam

Tags: php, flash, captcha, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blocking comment spam without using captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577918/blocking-comment-spam-without-using-captcha)

Most of the time Captcha is either broken by bots or by labor force working as data entry jobs in Asia. And then spam/content bots/scrappers get in.

What are other strong and effective alternatives available?

And I thought about something like on smartphones these days that it ask you to drag to  unlock. I think if that can be made in Adobe Flash or maybe using HTML5? .. do you think it will work effectively?

**Please note that emphasize is on defeating HUMAN + BOT partnership where human element comes from Asian countries to enter Captcha code or simple answers and then bots come into play.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472/practical-non-image-based-captcha-approaches , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448665/alternative-captcha-methods, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940887/need-alternatives-to-captcha

Comment: Perhaps my favorite captcha link discussing the various methods and their pros and cons: http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/PWNtcha

Answer (score 4):

Fighting spam is very difficult, in my experience.

I've had some success with content relevant questions. For instance, if your site is about computers, you could ask who is the major competitor to Intel. Another alternative is just show an image without text, and let users enter what they see (eg. a chip, a printer, ...)

Unfortunately, some spammers register as real human beings.

I have also implemented on my forum email domain bans, as many spammers use temporary email services.

Of course, I you want to effectively fight spambots registered by real users, I think you're doomed to IP white or blacklists, but I'd consider that a last measure.

Comment: Email domain bans? My personal email is @dotancohen.com, would I be banned from your forum?

Comment: I have same problem a group from Ukrain have both human and bots and they work together to spam. If you do a little search then you will find spammers are using cheap labor force to get in to and advertise as captcha data entry jobs and they can also answer simple question.

Comment: No, but domains like yopmail.com and guerillamail.com are blocked, because they provide the ability to create temporary email addresses. More than 80% of spammers in the last 2 weeks on my site were with emails from these domains.