# How to make one step Human Verification like in StackOverflow?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Captcha without session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465704/php-captcha-without-session)

That after I send a form I get to captcha page - than I go back to the form?
How to do it?
Should I use session?

I know how to implement captcha on form page 
but I wonder how it's done:
that I get redirected to verification page ex. https://stackoverflow.com/captcha?s=f689274e-e760-482d-a008-31d4bd469f80

I don't need any specific explanation - I would like to get an idea.

Comment: whoa! thats a very broad question. I think you should edit it to be more specific and include some code examples. At the moment the scope is too broad!

Comment: Well, the form receival page decides that it requires authorization. So it saves all $_POST fields into $_SESSION, sends a Location: redirect to the captcha page. The captcha page redirects to itself, detects previous $_SESSION[_POST] values, then redirects again to the form receival page. Form processing verifies that the captcha authorization flag is set, then finally uses the stored previous _POST values for example.

Answer (score 0):

[Recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha) has easy-to-install plugins, all you have to do is get it and follow the instructions.