# A captcha and forced registration still isn't stopping robot spam

Tags: captcha, recaptcha, spam-prevention

I'm using the phpdug template at http://fantasybookmark.com and there's still spam coming through.  What additional steps should I take?  Is recaptcha THAT much better than the captcha system in place here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The captcha you have there is extremely weak... very easy for a program like `teseract` to break. And yes, ReCAPTCHA *is* a much better quality CAPTCHA.

Comment: Appreciate it - going to attempt to implement recaptcha

Answer (score 1):

It is common secret that bots easily pass reCAPTCHA. You can find references and code for this by internet searching, but do not use google since it bought reCAPTCHA and suppresses such searches

Even if not, reCAPTCHA does not protect from automatic engagement of sweat shops (on failing to automatically circumvent reCAPTCHA) integrated in many professional spam bots. That is, nothing in it prevents to screenshot reCAPTCHA and pass it for solution to 3d party human solvers. See [my other answer on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472/practical-non-image-based-captcha-approaches/4489395#4489395)