# Should a honeypot captcha be more complicated than 'display: none;'?

Tags: security, captcha, honeypot

I'm needing to implement some form of captcha support for comments on my blog. I would really prefer a mostly passive approach, as in, no ReCaptcha. I'm thinking about doing a combination of [honeypot](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/11/honeypot-captcha.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472/practical-non-image-based-captcha-approaches/8637#8637). I don't exactly plan for my site to be specifically targeted by any spammers, but I want to definitely stop all the drive-by spam attacks.

So on to my question: With spam bots advancing in technology all the time, should I use something more complicated for hiding the hidden field than `display: none`? If so, then what would you suggest?

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/04/in-search-of-the-perfect-captcha) article inspiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless spam is a serious problem on your blog, I'd just go for doing `display: none`.

You could also try the classic "What is 2 + 2" / "What color is the sky?" style questions.

Comment: I guess anything to make a spammers job just a tiny bit harder is enough to stop 99% of spammers.

Comment: *What color is the sky?* Bah, I live in Scotland. Grey.

Answer (score 1):

for human verification:
I use a php function to generate a random number string, and echo it into a text box. Then require the user to enter it into a blank box. I use jQuery .validate to make sure the two are equal to each other.

for bot detection:
I use a hidden input and then with my jQuery .validate script I make a custom rule that if the hidden input's value isn't blank it returns an error I also have this in my server side php validation. works pretty well.