# Unwanted garbage input into HTML form via bot?

Tags: security

I have a website where I have a job section.  I allow applicants fill out job applications online.  No login is required.  The data input gets stored in a database.

I have NOT put any captcha or bot blocking mechanism in the HTML form.  I understand that this is a dumb thing to do.  But mine is a small website and I did not spend too much time programming this.

I see every once in a while garbage inputs into the application form fields like the following:

yRERRCEXEUOMCew

Some times the 'City' field in the data would have a valid input (such as New York)

I am trying to understand where does this input come from and what would anyone gain by doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from spam bots and they just submit random information to check to see if it is a working form or can send email, etc. If you are looking for a non-intrusive method (i.e. no CAPTCHA or JavaScript) to prevent spam bots from submitting bogus data, I would highly recommend throttling form submissions. If you are using PHP, you could use code like this:

```
// Sessions needed to tie forms to specific users
session_start();

// Process form here
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    $now = time();
    // See if the current time less the start time is less than or equal to 5 seconds
    if ( ( $now - $_SESSION['start_time'] )
```

Note: this will not stop dedicated bots nor will it provide any real security. It will stop automatic flood bots though since they will not normally wait 5 seconds between submissions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was really bothering me to find from where I was getting these intermittent input.  Thanks.  I will look into putting some anti-bot code.  I do use Perl.  I guess I can do something similar to what you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to understand where does this input come from ?

It can come from any where , a user can also input this as your app isn't validating this input.

> and what would anyone gain by doing this.

**No** Idea

---

You can put captcha. or simply you can add two attribute

lets say

1,98 and one operation sign(for example , `+`) let the user perform and validate this thing @ server.

---

**Also See**

- [Practical non-image based CAPTCHA approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472/practical-non-image-based-captcha-approaches)

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into what you have suggested.

Comment: you are welcomed ( also to mark this as an answer if it is for you)