# How to stop spammers from registering on my site?

Tags: php, spam, akismet

I am using akismet to check for comment spam, and it works. However, I would also like to stop them from registering in the first place.

Is there something I can use like akismet to check the registration details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just implement [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)?

Comment: reCaptcha is to split users and bots, but not to split spam users and good users. Also, there are captcha solving services with API and human cheap resources at the backend, so lots of bots solve captcha with no problem.

Comment: ... see this post for discussion about using Akismet to stop spam registrations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414232/registration-spammer-detection-with-akismet

Comment: Still lot of spams :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try making ip address validation, it could help you make every registration unique. While the form submit, you could check with the other registered users' ip address and restrict multiple registration of the spammers from the same id, as they(spammers) usually make multiple ids and probably from a same computer.

Useful source:

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Comment: Nowadays it is highly common for different people/machines to have the same public IP because they are behind a NAT router; Not to mention that spammers can quite easily spoof their IP. Perhaps a combination of IP and user-agent string.. take a look at http://samy.pl/evercookie/

Comment: Good to know, :) but i usually use ip address validation and yes, it reduces the spammers drastically.

Comment: IP address validate  will be blocking someone who is considered to be a spammer, even though he is not a spammer.

Simple way, use a captcha to avoid spam robots.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add some [captcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) to your registration form. Adding an anti [cross site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) field also helps.