# Alternative to Recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha

Ours is a java web application on struts2 framework. Currently for contact us form and download reports form we are using Recaptcha. We have to refresh the captcha at least 4-5 times to get the readable words. We are looking for some simple alternative to Recaptcha which prevents getting Spam requests. 
Guys can you suggest me a replacement for Recaptcha.

Comment: am Googling it, but wanted to know from guys who have already worked on other stuffs  than Recaptcha.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Even stackoverflow is using that now if you use unavailable tags. There are other solutions available out there. I am looking for something that works and if I find one I will post back

Comment: BTW, you will most likely get bad reps for this post but I am sure you can afford it... I posted a similar question yesterday and already people are giving negative comments saying I am doing something wrong. The only thing I know is that I am not going to AGGRAVATE my visitors by using reCAPTCHA in my site

Comment: I used [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8637/569101) since few weeks now, and I'm very happy with it. Btw, check the whole question/answers, interesting topic;

Comment: This is the first result when Googling the question, your SEO is awesome guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, another example of an alternate captcha is this: you can make a slide of images, and place one behind the slider.  Then, let the human chose from the slider which image is behind the slider.

(I have seen it in a forum, but I don't remember the name of website where I have seen this type of captcha)

You can also make your forum like no one can copy paste anything there, means pasting is restricted there.

Answer (score 4):

I found this! http://areyouahuman.com/

Just discovered it. Plan to use on my next project.

Answer (score 3):

Images are far more easy to identify compared to garbled text. They are more difficult to break too. You could use image-identification CAPTCHAs such as [these](http://www.picatcha.com).