# Alternative to captcha

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm looking at adding a bit of security to a form to avoid spammers and bots.

I know I can add a captcha, but I really don't like these as they look clunky.

I've seen other places that have things such as `What is 2 + 2?` and `What colour is an orange?`

Is there a bundle / library / example of implementing a question-based 'captcha'?

Comment: See this question, you would get a lot of options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472/practical-non-image-based-captcha-approaches

Comment: Take a look at [Packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=captcha)

Comment: You can just have a hidden field as the first element in your form. Bots won't know to avoid it, whereas genuine users will not see it - then if the element contains something, ignore the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way you can do like:

1. When form is getting open, then generate some long token key
2. Store this long token key on one table as well.
3. After submitting the form, check for the token key, if exists, then insert and remove that token key from table as well.
4. If token key not found on table, then ignore insertion of data.