# Reduce Form Spam

Tags: javascript, php, forms, spam

I typically only do front-end UI. But, on a project I have been working on I had to make a form. The form works, with emails coming through, but unfortunately an incredibly large amount of spam is coming through. I've added a CAPTCHA input but that doesn't seem to have reduced the amount of spam very much if at all.

After some research, it seems a honeypot is the best option. However because I don't know a lot about php and javascript (working on this :) ), I'm not sure what the best code for this is or where to put it.

However I haven't been able to find a clear guide on how to do this.

So my question is; Does anyone know of a clear guide that has instruction on how to make and implement a honeypot input (with the server side conditional code)?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. The form is "in a lightbox", so that may affect things.

Comment: what are your current form fields, do you believe these attacks are automated?

Comment: Sorry but after answering I found it's already a SO duplicate.

Comment: @robbmj The attacks are almost definitely automated, based on the amount coming through and the nature of the messages. Are looking for the coding or the name of the fields (sorry if this has an obvious answer)?

Comment: no worries, I hope you find the dup link an effective solution to stop the attacker(s). Good luck.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of methods here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472/practical-non-image-based-captcha-approaches

Comment: Most worryingly, apparently the CAPTCHA is doing nothing to stop automated attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form>
  <input name="not-honeypot" type="text">
  <input name="honeypot" type="text" style="display: none">
</form>
```

---

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['honeypot'])) {
    // this is a spam!
}
```

---

Note `display: none` for `[name=honeypot]`. If your spammers a smart enough to not fill hidden fields, you need another way to hide honeypot field from a user. Or not hide it at all.

Comment: I find javascript even better than style, since it should be even more difficult to detect than css. Furthermore, names like 'honeypots' might be automatically matched, so you'd need a not-obvious name. Still good answer +1

Comment: You might use `position: absolute; left: -99999px` instead of `display: none`

Comment: Actually, using `if (!empty($_POST['honeypot'])) { die(); }` as the 1st line (after `<?php` ) would stop anything from getting to the `mail()` function ever to be reached.

Comment: I think this might be what I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's actually really simple. I'll attempt from memory, so typos are expected. You can always google for a more solid answer as I'm sure there're few tutorials out there.

## html:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "post.php">
  <input type = "email" name = "email>
  <input type = "email" name = "emailb">
  <input type = "submit">
</form>
```

## Javascript (jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".another[attribute='emailb']").hide();
  });
```

## post.php:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['emailb']))
  throw new Exception("SPAAAAM");
```

You need to do it with javascript as most automated bots won't be using it. However, you also want to check for the number of forms sent in X minutes from that IP and few other options to prevent even more. Note: don't automatically dissable it, show a recaptcha as a last-line measure.

Comment: Would the fact that is contained within a "lightbox" not affect the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

## Firsly, Define what `spam` is / could be:

Spam could consist of:
1. **More uppercase charcters than lowercase**
2. **More whitespaces than text**
3. **Very short posts (eg 10 characters long)**

## Then, Write code to deal with it

```
1. if (strlen(preg_replace('![^A-Z]+!', '', $post)) > strlen(preg_replace('![^a-z]+!', '', $post))){
//spam post
}

2. if(!isset($post) || strlen(strip_tags($post))<150){
//too short - spam post
}

3. if (strlen(preg_replace('/\S/', '', $post)) > strlen(preg_replace('/\s+/', '',     $post)))
{
//spam post
}
```

This will not stop the spam, but it should filter quite a bit of it.

Comment: I'm certain he's refering to [Spam (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_%28electronic%29).

Comment: Yes I know that @FranciscoPresencia

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia this is a validation form server side that will work better than a honeypot will. Never trust the client